# AngularJS - issue with dropdown menu in <select> tag, can't have 2 custom option while using ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, select

I have a `<select>` that loops over an array of data and displays the selections available in the dropdown list.

the markup is like this:

```
 <select required class="form-control btn-primary btn dropdown-toggle"
    ng-options="s.name for s in list track by s.name" ng-model="list">
    <option selected value=""></option>
    <option value="" ng-click="">Split</option>
</select>
```

What I want is, to have the preselected value as an empty string, I achieved that with:

```
<option selected value=""></option>
```

but then I need a second custom `<option>` tag besides all the `<option>` tags that get generated by the ng-option,

in this tag I need to show a string, in this case "split", and there will be a ng-click on this `option` so the user can click on it and a second dropdown will appear.

The problem is the second `<option>` tag it's not shown, only the first one, and I did some tests, and apparently I can show only one option tag besides the ones from `ng-option`.

Is there a solution for this?

What I need as end result is my `option` list generated by `ng-option`,
then a preselected `option` that is EMPTY (it shows when the user loads the page), and a second `option` with a custom string that will be used like a button.

Here a jsfiddle where you can see that the second custom option tag isnt shown

https://jsfiddle.net/0xyt24sh/10/

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to have more than one hard-coded option with [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), as explicitly mentioned in the documentation:

> Optionally, a single hard-coded  element, with the value set
>   to an empty string, can be nested into the  element. This
>   element will then represent the null or "not selected" option.

A workaround might be to use `ngRepeat`:

```
<select class="form-control btn-primary btn dropdown-toggle" ng-model="selection">
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option ng-repeat="s in list">{{s.name}}</option>
    <option ng-click="" value="split">Split</option>
</select>
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0xyt24sh/17/

Comment: thank you, I used in the past multiple hard-coded option tags, but as you said, I think the rest was looped over a ng-repeat, and I forgot so I thought it should be possible

Answer (score 0):

From [ngOptions documentation:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

> Optionally, a single hard-coded  element, with the value set to an empty string, can be nested into the  element. This element will then represent the null or "not selected" option. See example below for demonstration.

In this case, `ngOptions` isn't fit for your problem; Instead, you can use `<option>`s with `ng-repeat`, as such:

```
<select required class="form-control btn-primary btn dropdown-toggle" ng-model="selected">
   <option selected value=""></option> 

   <option ng-repeat="item in list track by item.code">
     {{item.name}}
   </option>

   <option value="split" ng-click="doSomething()">Split</option>       
 </select>
```

[Working JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Protozoid/y3gh5vp4/)